# If statement for jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

How to make this right?

```
$(this).click(function(){
   if(showLarge == 1 && !$('.loginLarge_wrap')){
     //
   }
});
```

The idea here is that, there's a condition showLarge equals to 1 and not equals to .loginLarge_wrap

Thank you.

Comment: What is `!$('.loginLarge_wrap')` supposed to express?

Comment: what is `showLarge`? a string? a number? jQuery object? what?

Comment: do you want to check if an element with css class `loginLarge_wrap` doesn't exit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).click(function() {
    if ( ( showLarge == 1 ) && ( showLarge != $('.loginLarge_wrap' ) ) ) {
        //
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery method - hasClass() to check to see if   the class - '.loginLarge_wrap' is present instead of doing

```
showLarge != $('.loginLarge_wrap' )
```

Assuming showLarge is a DOM element.
you can do something like this:

```
if($(showLarge).val() == 1 && (!$(showLarge).hasClass('.loginLarge_wrap')))
```